# Get rid of numbering in "remark" environment

Tags: numbering, environments

I use `renewcommand` for changing the remark into my native language, more precise, I used :

```
\renewcommand\remarkname{Chú ý}
```

It goes with a counter, i.e each time I start a remark

```
\begin{remark}
this is remark
\end{remark}
```

it will give me the output that

```
Chú ý 1. This is remark.
```

My quesstion is : How can I remove the counter in this environment to get only :

```
Chú ý. This is remark.
```

Please help me. Thanks.

**EDIT** As Mico has commented, I added here a MWE, that is a shortened version of my latex template :

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountsec,sectrefs,vecarrow,envcountretsec]{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\savesymbol{hbar}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}           
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{esvect}   
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand\remarkname{Chú ý}
\begin{document}
\begin{remark}
This is remark
\end{remark}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more information -- preferably in the form of an MWe (minimum working example) that generates the problem behavior you're trying to fix -- about any packages you load that provide the `remark` environment. Having this information will be crucial for determining how best an unnumbered version of the `remark` environment might be made available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svmono document class uses its own internal commands to define theorem-like structures; for example:

```
\spn@wtheorem{remark}{Remark}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
```

The line above declares a structure for a numbered environment `remark` that will typeset "Remark"; the headfont will be italics and the body font will be `\rmfamily`.

To change this, using the already defined `remark` environment, one has to first, "undo" the default definition and then use `\spnewtheorem*` for an unnumbered structure:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}
\let\remark\relax
\let\endremark\relax

\spnewtheorem*{remark}{Remark}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand\remarkname{Chú ý}

\begin{document}

\begin{remark}
This is remark.
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The other option would be to declare a brand new unnumbered structure:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam]{babel}

\newcommand\remaname{}
\spnewtheorem*{rema}{\remaname}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\renewcommand\remaname{Chú ý}

\begin{document}

\begin{rema}
This is remark.
\end{rema}

\end{document}
```